# Centering Dynamic width Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has 2 columns.  The first column is a dynamic width.  It contains a bunch of tabular data in tables.  The 2nd column is a fixed width full of navigation stuff.

The 2 columns are divs with float left.  I need to accomplish 2 things.

1. I need to center the 2 divs on the page.  For example, if the first div is 600px wide as dictated by the data inside of it and the second div is a fixed 200px, the centering point is 400px.
2. I don't want the 2nd div to wrap down if the browser window is resized.

I'm thinking that I may have to nest the 2 divs inside of another div, set the parent div width using javascript, then center it.

I created this fiddle to help illustrate.  http://jsfiddle.net/darthg8r/uhKdt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround them with a div and set its style to:

```
width: ( whatever you need )
margin: 0 auto; // this centers the div
```

You can set the width dynamically with JavaScript if needed. As long as it's smaller than 100% of the surrounding container, it will stay centered.

Comment: OP specifically says the container width is unknown.

Comment: I've decided that I can't do it without adding the container div and using javascript.  It actually works ok, but I am a bit worried about cross browser compat and a "flash" as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="variable">test</div>
        <div id="fixed">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
#container { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%; }
#container > div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    height: 300px; }
#variable { 
    background: red;
    width: 300px; }
#fixed { 
    background: blue;
    width: 200px; }
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/mreLt/

You could also achieve this effect by wrapping the two elements in a container, setting them both to `display: inline-block`, and finally setting their container to have `text-align: center`.
<s>*The answer is a little more complicated than this, so let me know if you want to choose this route instead.*</s>

To make it so the elements don't fall to the next line, use `inline-block`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="variable">
        <p>test</p>
    </div><div id="fixed">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; }
#container { 
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap; }
#container > div {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block; }
#variable { 
    background: red;
    width: 100px; }
#fixed { 
    background: blue;
    width: 200px; }
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/mreLt/2/

Comment: The variable column in your example isn't truely variable.  Simply setting the width a little bigger in the css breaks it.  In my scenario, I don't know the width of the variable column until runtime.

Comment: I made some edits - This should prevent your page from flashing.